# How to handle multiple session variables in ASP .Net?

Tags: asp.net, session, cart

As a part of online shopping, I implemented a cart using Session.
I have implemented the Cart in the following manner :

```
Session[pname] = qty;
```

where `pname` is a string variable which holds the name of the product and I used that as the key. `qty` is an integer variable which holds the number of items of that particular product.
To display the cart items I simply used the following loop :

```
foreach(string keys in Session.Keys)
```

Through this I get the names of the products along with the associated quantity and using this I display the cart items. The problem arises when I also have a session for the user active on the same page.

```
Session["uname"] = user_name;
```

And while retrieving the keys using Session.Keys, the `uname` gets included which I don't want as I need only the product's names. Is there any way I can read the keys from `Session[pname]` without reading from `Session["uname"]`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing an object in session for each product and quantity, just store a single object (e.g. `List`) which contains all of your cart items.

Here is an example which you could tweak to meet your needs:

First, a simple object to store the data:

```
public class CartItem {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Then if you need to add an object to the cart list:

```
var cartItems = new List<CartItem>();

cartItems.Add(new CartItem() {
    Name = "",
    Quantity = 1
});

Session["Cart"] = cartItems;

//Need to fetch the cart items later on?
cartItems = (List<CartItem>)Session["Cart"];
```

Obviously this can be implemented differently and this was just a quick example.

Comment: I can implement the cart using list but for that I would have to change a lot of code, I need some quick fixes for this particular method and my problem is also centered on multiple session variables. If there is a way I will use that. Else I will use this solution to rebuild the code which I am not exactly inclined to do.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned needing an easier fix than what Justin Helgerson said, so here's a couple of suggestions, but they feel a little quick and dirty. Justin's is probably the superior solution. I used a quick Console app to demonstrate this, so place your constants where they belong, and you obviously don't have to create a dictionary.

```
const string USERSESSION = "uname";
Dictionary<string, object> session = new Dictionary<string, object>();
session["item1"] = 2;
session["item2"] = 1;
session[USERSESSION] = "StackOverflowUser";

// print cart items - minus the user name session key
foreach (string key in session.Keys.Where(s => s != USERSESSION))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} Value: {1}", key, session[key]);
}
```

Alternatively, if you plan on there being more keys than just `"uname"`, use the Linq [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
// build up except set
List<string> exceptKeys = new List<string>
{
    USERSESSION
};

foreach (string key in session.Keys.Except(exceptKeys))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} Value: {1}", key, session[key]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem is only "uname" that is why I needed a quick fix. And I agree Justin Helgerson's solution IS superior. But I would have to rebuild the code. Anyway, I will try this out. :)